# How does the COM interface pointer work?

Tags: c++, com

I'm new to COM programming and is reading other's code years ago. I get something puzzling.
There are some interface poiters declared in the header file. For example the m_pPhone highlighted in yellow.

[image]

After declared, m_pPhone seems not get any value or assignment or initialization.
[image]

But it is used to get the m_pPhone->PhoneMode value. Where is the value coming from? The project is compiled as DLL. I didn't find any included lib in the project property. The platform is Windows 7.

[image]

Added:VS2010 hint message show the definition, but by F12 or by findstr CMD, can't find it.
[image]

Comment: Please include the relevant code, not *pictures* of the code.

Comment: Sorry, the projects are large and very fragmented and actually I didn't know how to generalize the problem clearly. Any possible indication or surmise or related summary is helpful to me.

Comment: First, figure out if you're dealing with a ATL COM smart pointer or a compiler COM smart pointer. For ATL ones, make sure you read up about [`CComPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98.aspx) and [How to: Create and Use CComPtr and CComQIPtr Instances](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279683.aspx). For compiler ones, read [`_com_ptr_t`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-ptr-t-class) and [Compiler COM Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/compiler-com-support).

Comment: From the looks of it, I think the smart classes are created by [`#import('AtlasPhone')`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) so that would make compiler COM smart pointers (the `_com_ptr_t` kind).

Comment: `m_pPhone` is likely using a smart pointer class of some kind. It's own constructor will initialize the contained pointer to null. So `m_pPhone` does not need to be explicitly initialized in the `CDownloadAgent` constructor. But just because it is not initialized in the constructor does not mean it is not ever initialized at all. There is likely code elsewhere in the class that initializes `m_Phone` on demand when it is actually needed. Maybe in `MILockPhone()`.

Comment: OK. I do found the #import some .tlb file lines. And by your comment I know m_Phone should be initialized in somewhere. Previously I doubt if COM has some special way of implicitly initializing the smart pointer which won't show in code. Maybe I have missed something ( I didn't find anything special in the MILockPhone. m_Phone seems not be used as left value or parameters of any Init fuction, however I'll double check ).  I may need some time to fully understand rest of your comments after google/search MSDN for other concepts you have mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: The IAtlasPhonePtr is defined as typedef _com_ptr_t<sth.>  somelib::IAtlasPhonePtr . From VS2010, by moving mouse on the IAtlasPhonePtr, a hint message shows that typedef line. However, I can't search the typedef line by search string in the whole folder. It's really strange. Where does VS2010 retrieve the typedef line from in hint message which cannot be found by F12 or string searching in the whole solution?

Comment: The `IAtlasPhonePtr` type definition will be in the .h files *generated* during build. See the link to `#import`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `m_Phone` is a compiler COM smart pointer generated by the [`#import`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp). This directive will create, at build time, some .h files *in the build folders* and these files will in turn be compiled into your project, see [Header Files Created by Import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp#_predir_the_primary_type_library_header_file).

The value is assigned to the smart pointer usually by a call to [`CreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/com-ptr-t-createinstance), but it can also be assigned through other means (eg. by COM smart assignment of a method return or even a QueryInterface call). You have to constantly keep in mind that the real action that happens here is COM and goes by the COM rules, the compiler support just hides it and makes it look like ordinary C++ syntax.

Comment: The documents you provided is very helpful. Thanks!